# How to get Specific record while using group by

Tags: mysql

I have table with two columns for example table_data

```
id    value
1       2
1       5
1       4

select * from table_data group by id
```

but i got the output is 1 1..but actually i want this output for my desire example 1 4 or 1 5...
how to get that??

Comment: please specify if this is sql-server or mysql, and also provide more sample data.

Comment: Can't be ms sql, it would have returned a syntax error.

Comment: As answered by @Dylan, using MAX() will return "1 5" and MIN() will return "1 2". But as mentioned in question, "1 4" can not be returned in this case

Comment: Please explain why you want this output? give any logical reason. So anyone can suggest you anything without any vague ideas

Comment: i want 1,4 also...please help me out

Comment: Do you need both (1,4),(1,5) to appear in the output or just one of them ?

Comment: i want one output..but in the above case i gave the sample data..when i go to the original data it will contain large num...so i want the output whatever i need..

Comment: The value for columns which are not included in GROUP BY exprs are picked relying on the processing order for MySQL. You can't count on that.

Answer (score 0):

Use MAX with GROUP BY:

```
select id, MAX(value) from table_data group by id
```

If you need any of the value in group to appear in the result set, just GROUP BY is enough. But you need to know that, the output row is undetermined.

Normally, the first row it process will be put into output representing its group.

Here is a demo on this:

```
mysql> create table table_data(id int, value int);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> insert into table_data values (1,4),(1,5),(1,2);
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM table_data;
SEL+------+-------+
| id   | value |
+------+-------+
|    1 |     4 |
|    1 |     5 |
|    1 |     2 |
+------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM table_data GROUP BY id;
+------+-------+
| id   | value |
+------+-------+
|    1 |     4 |
+------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: In the above query it will only return max value...but i want all the possible values...

Comment: @madeit Updated the post. Pls check.

Comment: You state "i want all the possible values" but are using a "group by". The definition of "group by" is contrary to that statement.  Unless you are looking to concatenate the three "value" entries so as to return: "id = 1, value = 2,5,4".

Answer (score 0):

You can use the aggregate function using this you can get the max value from it [MAX function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-maximum-column.html)

```
SELECT id, MAX(value) 
FROM table_data 
GROUP BY id
```

Answer (score 0):

select id,max(value) from table_data group by id

this will return 1, 5

select id,min(value) from table_data group by id

this will return 1,2 .

in this case 1, 4 is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, MAX(value) 
FROM table_data 
GROUP BY id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select m.id,m.value from
(SELECT * FROM table_data order by field(value,4,2,5))m
group by m.id
```

we can get whatever the output we want...

by made it